# 2 Lists, a loop and a login

Tags: python, list, loops, authentication

I have two lists, one of User IDs and one of passwords. I alread have a script that logs into a website and scrapes out the data i need...

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from mechanize import Browser
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
import easygui

br = Browser()
hid = easygui.enterbox (msg="Enter Hotel ID", title="HID", default="", strip=True)
pwd = easygui.enterbox (msg="Enter Password", title="HID", default="", strip=True)
url = "http://example.com"
page = br.open(url)
#Select form on front page, input values and submit
br.select_form(nr=0)
br["UN"] = hid
br["txtID"] = pwd
results = br.submit().read()

#Printing XML results to a file by appending
myfile = open('C:\\Python\\xml\\output.xml','a')
myfile.write(results)
myfile.close()

#Printing txt results to a file by appending
myfile = open('C:\\Python\\xml\\output.txt','a')
myfile.write(results)
myfile.close()
```

So i input the login/password details when easygui gives me the prompt to do so. If i store all the passwords in two lists...

```
userlist = ['254376xml', '254371xml', '245157xml', '244829xml', '242404xml', '238153xml', '235884xml', '28551xml']
pwordlist = ['mbhg934uh', 'hj2r93kh8s', 'mhg90wihf', 'ng0218hkd', 'nb029hkegh', 'bng0219hk', 'mg029k03g', 'mntg0ohwf']
```

I've tried using the integer loop to import the values one at a time for each iteration of the loop and i've tried with no success. I've looked for some help and tutorials on how i can do this but nothing that seems to fit my specific needs. Can anyone point me in the right direction or suggest what code i can use to implement this feature.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to check that the password a user enters is correct, you would be better off storing them in a dictionary like below. You'll need to populate the rest of the dictionary where I've put `...`.

```
passwords = { '254376xml': 'mbhg934uh', '254371xml': 'hj2r93kh8s', ... }
def check_password(username, password):
  if username not in passwords:
    return False # username not found
  return password == passwords[username] # check the password is correct
```

Then call it like this:

```
>>> check_password('254371xml', 'hj2r93kh8s') # correct password
True
>>> check_password('254371xml', 'wrong') # wrong password
False
>>> check_password('non-existant', 'wrong') # non-existant user
False
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, i'm trying to loop the program so each time it picks up the next item from each of the lists. Uses the items to login and scrape the data from the website and then go through the loop again with the next two bits of information.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I understand your requirements completely. Do you want to iterate over both lists in parallel, extracting corresponding username/password pairs in each iteration?

If so, then

```
userlist = ['254376xml', '254371xml', '245157xml', '244829xml', '242404xml', '238153xml', '235884xml', '28551xml']
pwordlist = ['mbhg934uh', 'hj2r93kh8s', 'mhg90wihf', 'ng0218hkd', 'nb029hkegh', 'bng0219hk', 'mg029k03g', 'mntg0ohwf']
for username, password in zip(userlist, pwordlist):
    print "Username:", username, " - Password:", password
print "Done!"
```

should do.

But if you're asking if there is a better data structure for this, then I recommend marcog's dictionary solution.

Comment: That is what i want and using your example i can get it to pick up the first user/pword. But it will only output the first pair not all the pairs. I'm sure i'm just missing a line to run the loop again.

Comment: This is strange; it should loop through all of them. I'll edit my post with a complete sample.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you try to acghieve is this ( Code taken from other answers)

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from mechanize import Browser
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
import easygui

br = Browser()
userlist = ['254376xml', '254371xml', '245157xml', '244829xml', '242404xml', '238153xml', '235884xml', '28551xml']
pwordlist = ['mbhg934uh', 'hj2r93kh8s', 'mhg90wihf', 'ng0218hkd', 'nb029hkegh', 'bng0219hk', 'mg029k03g', 'mntg0ohwf']

for username, password in zip(userlist, pwordlist):

    url = "http://example.com"
    page = br.open(url)
    #Select form on front page, input values and submit
    br.select_form(nr=0)
    br["UN"] = username
    br["txtID"] = password
    results = br.submit().read()

    #Printing XML results to a file by appending
    myfile = open('C:\\Python\\xml\\output.xml','a')
    myfile.write(results)
    myfile.close()

    #Printing txt results to a file by appending
    myfile = open('C:\\Python\\xml\\output.txt','a')
    myfile.write(results)
    myfile.close()
```